# Trying to Create a Search Bar in TkSheet

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, search, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to create a search bar with TkSheet where I take a user entry and use it to highlight the contents in a TkSheet, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help appreciated TkSheet doesn't have great documentation.

```
    # setup tksheet to display csv
    self.prev_frame = tk.Frame(bot_left_frame)
    self.sheet = sheet.Sheet(self.prev_frame, data=df_row, headers=col_list, width=850, height=550)
    self.sheet.change_theme('light blue')
    self.sheet.header_font(newfont=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
    self.sheet.font(newfont=("Helvetica", 12, "normal"))
    self.sheet.set_all_cell_sizes_to_text(redraw=True)

    # highlight the cell based on the text in the entry field
    self.sheet.highlight_cells(cells=search_var, bg='yellow', redraw=True)  # THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK

    self.sheet.enable_bindings()
    self.prev_frame.pack()
    self.sheet.pack()

    # create a search bar to highlight contents in the sheet
    self.search_item = tk.Entry(bot_left_toolbar, width=30)
    self.search_item.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.search_item.focus_set()
    tk.Button(bot_left_toolbar, text='Search Sheet', font=('Helvetica', 14),
              command=self.search_sheet).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
```

[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87odH.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why do you think the code is "going wrong"? What is it doing, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: I plugged the user entry value [search_var] into the cells parameter to search it and I get an error 'for r_, c_ in cells: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)'

My goal is to be able to insert a string in here to search the table for matching strings and highlight the ones that match. Sorry I should've clarified.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include the stacktrace.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find that, I'm using PyCharm ide where should I go?

Comment: I don't know. I don't use pycharm.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I attached an image of the stack trace

Comment: Please don't post images of code or stack traces. They aren't searchable, and the visually impaired can't see them at all.

Comment: The `cells` argument expects a list of (row, col) instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any good documentation on if the highlight_cells method could search for a certain cell value on its own. However I found you can use the built in python functions to search the arrays you put into/take out of the sheet to find the row/column values and use those to highlight the value

```
    search_var = input("Please input search variable: ")

    if(search_var in NamesList):
        Row = NamesList.index(search_var)
        Column = 0

    elif(search_var in ValuesList):
        Row = NamesList.index(search_var)
        Column = 1

    elif(search_var in ListNamesList):
        Row = NamesList.index(search_var)
        Column = 2

    elif(search_var in ListValuesList):
        Row = NamesList.index(search_var)
        Column = 3

    else:
        print("Value not found!")

    sheet.highlight_cells(row = Row, column = Column, bg='yellow', redraw=True)
```